# How to send multiple parameters to exe from c# code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, exe

I am trying to invoke exe from C# code . If I run the exe from command prompt like below , it works fine

```
C:\abc\abc.exe -e dev -l line1 -q 1
```

I am trying to invoke the same exe by passing all three parameters but none of the parameter get pass to exe if I see it in Trace. Can someone tell me how to pass it .

Here is the code

```
string[] cParams = new string[] { "dev", "Line1", "1" };

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(exePath, "abc.exe"));
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + cParams[0] + " " + cParams[1] + " " + cParams[2] + "\"";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;    
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: try without quotes: startInfo.Arguments = " " + cParams[0] + " " + cParams[1] + " " + cParams[2];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enclosing it in quotes you are in effect passing only one parameter.  You are also leaving out the switches (`-e`, `-l`, `-q`).  I believe you want:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(exePath, "abc.exe"));
startInfo.Arguments = "-e dev -l line1 -q 1";
```

Or if your "arguments" come from the array:

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-e {0} -l {1} -q {2}", cParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your arguments string, it's coming out to `"dev Line1 1"`. This would be the equivalent to calling

```
C:\abc\abc.exe "dev Line1 1"
```

You can either simplify your arguments:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "-e dev -l line1 -q 1";
```

Or fix the string you're building to remove the quotes, and append your "-e", "-l", etc:

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-e {0} -l {1} -q {2}", cParams[0], cParams[1], cParams[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're wrapping all the parameters in quotes. If you wrap each parameter in quotes individually, it should work.

Comment: Why are these CORRECT answers getting down voted with no comment?

Comment: Perhaps because there is no need to wrap them in individual quotes and the answer is to remove the existing quotes? This answer does not give an example of how it could be fixed. Try writing longer and more precise answers. Just an idea.

Comment: You also didn't mention that the switches are missing.

Comment: @Thomas, Maybe try comprehending the answer. The correct approach is in fact to wrap each parameter in quotes because they may contain white space. If you actually follow the advice I gave, you would find it works. Although I did miss the switches, but following my advice would have resulted  in a different error and being closer to the end solution. The down vote is laughable.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote. You wanted to know a reason, so I gave you one. Regarding the quotes: what would you do if one of the arguments already contains a quote? How do you escape that then? You see, an answer is not so simple.

Comment: @Thomas, Good point. The correct answer is still to quote the parameters. Whether you do or don't, embedded quotes will break things if they are not dealt with.