# How to pass multiple parameters (more than 3) to exe from c# code

Tags: c#

I am trying to call an exe from C# code, and I need to pass 2 arrays (array1, array2)， 1 N×3 matrix(M1) and 2 numbers(int1, double2). I find a question which is similar to mine:[How to send multiple parameters to exe from c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357415/how-to-send-multiple-parameters-to-exe-from-c-sharp-code)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(exePath, "abc.exe")); 

string[] cParams = new string[] { "dev", "Line1", "1" };

startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-e {0} -l {1} -q {2}", cParams);
```

can anyone tell me how to solve my problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the exe support such command-line parameters?

Comment: Have a look at `MemoryMappedFile` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx; so your `exe` and `abc.exe` will have a file(s) in memory to interact (e.g. pass and return arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are always strings. The only way to pass arrays or matrices to a program through the arguments is to convert it to a string. Note that your target application should also work with this format and will have to deserialize it back.

Now, it is up to your implementation. As for me, I would recommend using JSON and JSON.NET library for this:

```
// Serialize array to a string
int[] vals = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string valsArgument = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vals); // "[1,2,3,4,5]"

// In your target application
int[] vals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(argument1);
```

The array has been transfered from a calling application to the called one.

Note that it may be a bad idea to use arguments in that way. Probably, you need to use external files or something else.

Answer (score 0):

A concole-application (which I assume you refer to) can handle any number of parameters provided as an array of strings. And thats the problem with your arrays: you cannot pass anything different then simple strings. Thus you may flatten your arrays but you´ll lose any information that the parameters belong together. You might add a length-param for every array but that becomes quite annoying I guess: `myapp.exe v11 v12 v13 3 v21 v22 2 v33 v34 v35 v36 4` which would mean something like

> take the first three params and join them into one single array, then
>   do the same with the following two and four params appropriately

What you can do instead is to write all those parameters to an external file (JSON, XML) that mirrors the structure of your parameters and read them within your app using some kinf of deserialization.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DataContractJsonSerializer in .NET to serialize your paras into a string. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data/) is the example.

```
// Create a User object and serialize it to a JSON stream.  
public static string WriteFromObject()  
{  
    //Create User object.  
    User user = new User("Bob", 42);  

    //Create a stream to serialize the object to.  
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  

    // Serializer the User object to the stream.  
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new 
    DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(User));  
    ser.WriteObject(ms, user);  
    byte[] json = ms.ToArray();  
    ms.Close();  
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length);  
}  

// Deserialize a JSON stream to a User object.  
public static User ReadToObject(string json)  
{  
    User deserializedUser = new User();  
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));  
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new 
    DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedUser.GetType());  
    deserializedUser = ser.ReadObject(ms) as User;  
    ms.Close();  
    return deserializedUser;  
}
```